# Print out specific field using regular expression in Linux

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to print lines that have a 4th field value of 1001 or 1003 from a file called `mypasswd`. 
I can only use grep or egrep with regular expressions. 
Here is the file:

```
daemon:x:2:2:Daemon 1001:/sbin:/bin/bash
ftp:x:40:49:FTP export account:/srv/ftp:/bin/bash
daemonuser:x:50:59:nouser/bin/false:/home/nouser:/bin/bash
gdm:x:106:111:Gnome Display Mgr daemon:/var/lib/gdm:/bin/false
haldaemon:x:101:102:User for haldaemon:/var/run/hald:/bin/false
lp:x:4:7:Printing daemon:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/bash
mail:x:8:12:Mailer daemon:/var/spool/clientmqueue:/bin/false
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
sshd:x:71:65:SSH daemon:/var/lib/sshd:/bin/false
olivert:x:1001:1005:Tom Oliver:/home/olivert:/bin/csh
smiths:x:1049:1000:Sue Williams:/export/home/smiths:/bin/csh
northj:x:1003:1003:Jim jones-North:/home/northj:/bin/csh
denniss:x:1005:1003:Sue Dennis:/home/denniss:/bin/bash
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smithd:x:1055:1001:Dan Smith Jr:/export/home/smithd:/bin/csh
```

So the output should be

```
northj:x:1003:1003:Jim jones-North:/home/northj:/bin/csh
denniss:x:1005:1003:Sue Dennis:/home/denniss:/bin/bash
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smithd:x:1055:1001:Dan Smith Jr:/export/home/smithd:/bin/csh
```

I can easily just run `egrep '1001|1003' mypasswd`,
but that also gives me "daemon" (fifth field contains "1001")
and "olivert" (third field is "1001"). 
I'm just needing the 4th field values (values that are after three colons) that match those two numbers using egrep/grep regular expressions. Any answers are greatly appreciated, as they will help me out in the long run with this.

Comment: grep isn't the best solution here; a "robust" solution with grep would require matching & skipping the first three fields. Are you open to a more obvious solution with other tools, such as awk, or perl?

Comment: Per your comment on one of the answers, if you're required to use grep (perhaps because you're learning about grep and/or regular expressions in a class), please say so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would be more direct, in my opinion, to use a tool like `awk` that can:

- split fields for you
- test exactly the fields you want for the values you want

For example:

```
awk -F: '$4 == 1001 || $4 == 1003' mypasswd
```

... tells awk to:

- split the incoming lines into fields based on colons, with `-F:`
- uses an "or" expression to test whether field 4 has the value 1001 or 1003
- if the condition above is true, then print the line (the default action)

Awk can take a little bit to learn; one of the major things to understand about it is that it uses paired "pattern" and "action" statements. The "pattern" section(s) determine which "action" statements get executed.

You could rewrite the above awk to make it more explicit; by doing so, we can explicitly print whatever we want (such as the 5th field):

```
awk -F: '$4 == 1001 || $4 == 1003 { print $5 }'
```

... or to have an empty "pattern" section -- meaning, execute the "action" for *every* line, and then test inside the action pattern for the values:

```
awk -F: '{ if ($4 == 1001 || $4 == 1003)  print $5 }'
```

To force `grep` into action, you could do:

```
grep -E '^([^:]*:){3}(1001|1003):' mypasswd | cut -d: -f5
```

To tell it to look, from the beginning of the line, for the group "anything-that-isn't-a-colon any number of times, followed a colon" three times, followed by either 1001 or 1003, then followed by a colon; print the whole matching line, but then pass it to `cut` to print just the 5th field.

Comment: Thank you! The grep command worked really well! Wish I had enough rep to give you an upvote (lol).

Comment: Glad it helped; if you keep asking good questions, the rep will come naturally! Please do take note to say in your questions whether you have an artificial limitation of some sort; otherwise, people (like me) are prone to answering with tools that have fewer sharp edges. Give the question some time, and review the answers when you're ready. If any of them solved your question, there should be a checkmark next to it for you to click. Thanks, and welcome to U&L!

Comment: @JakeM, I think you do now :D

Comment: Or even `awk -F: '$4 ~ /1001|1003/ ...`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble except, as ilkkachu pointed out, using `/1001|1003/` would falsely match on e.g. 10010 or 10030.

Comment: You could anchor readily... awk supports ^$, no?

Comment: You'd want to anchor it, yep!

Answer (score 4):

I might do this with `sed`

```
sed -n '/^.*:.*:.*:\(1001\|1003\):/p' mypasswd
```

The `-n` supresses the lines and the `p` at the end prints the ones that match.

you could also do it with `grep`

```
grep '^.*:.*:.*:1002\|1003:.*:.*:' mypasswd
```

Comment: The `.*` can match an additional colon, so the `sed` solution here will also match lines where the gecos/comment field is `1001` or `1003`, but at least you have the trailing `:` to stop `10010` from matching. The `grep` solution seems fine since you have all the colons spelled out, ...that is unless someone has a `passwd` file with more fields than usual (I don't know if that would fly with other utilities though)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, I should have used non-greedy globs, but my regex skills are not that good to know which programs have greedy operators.

Comment: Non-greedy globs are a Perl thing, they don't work in the standard tools. `[^:]*` should work here since the delimiter is just one character.

Comment: Note that it assumes GNU `sed` or compatible for `\|`. Using `-E` and EREs may be more portable these days (it will be in the next major POSIX version). Same for `grep` (and `grep -E` has been standard for decades, `egrep` before that).

Comment: … or, *for this particular case*, you could use `100[13]`. That works only because `1001` and `1003` are the same except for one character; you wouldn’t be able to use that trick for `999\|1001` or even `1009\|1010`.

Answer (score 4):

As @JeffSchaller says, `awk` is the tool for the job and since OP wants `regex` we can just combine the two

```
awk -F: '$4 ~ /^100[13]$/' mypasswd
```

and that allows a little golf putt on the `grep` version

```
grep -E "^(.*:){3}100[13]:" mypasswd
```

Comment: Same comment as for others: the `grep` solution can match lines where the fourth field is `10010` (trailing digits), or where the _fifth_ field starts with `1001` (`.*` can match additional colons). The `awk` one can also match in the middle of the field, so `10010` and `11001` would match.

Comment: Fair comment, so the 4th field match needs anchoring at both ends in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I'm just needing the 4th field values (values that are after three colons) that match those two numbers using egrep/grep regular
>   expressions"*

If you just need the 4th field, use `cut` with `grep` like so:

```
$ cat mypasswd | cut -d: -f4 | grep -E '^(1001|1003)$'
1001
1003
```

The `grep` pattern needs to be anchored to the start and end of the line, otherwise it might match a number like `10010`. An alternative way to do that would be `grep -x -E '1001|1003'`.

Comment: hmm, shouldn't that be `cut -d: -f 4` for the fourth field? It's one-based in `cut`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank for adding missing anchors. 
Regarding the 4th element, you're right.
Regarding the regexp, there are many types to choose from, like: `cat mypasswd | cut -d: -f4 | grep '^100[1,3]$'` and similar. 
Also there's no need to escape the colon sign as it has no special meaning here.

Comment: Oh sure, there's also alternatives for the regex. I just mentioned `-x` since it occurred to me that it might look nicer than `^(..|..)$`.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory Perl solution(s):

Interpret the field as a number:

```
perl -F: -ane 'print if $F[3] == 1001 || $F[3] == 1003' mypasswd
```

or use a regex

```
perl -F: -ane 'print if $F[3] =~ /^(1001|1003)$/' mypasswd
```

or a somewhat shorter regex:

```
perl -F: -ane 'print if $F[3] =~ /^100[13]$/' mypasswd
```

or do some tricks with arithmetic (a bit tongue-in-cheek this one):

```
perl -F: -ane 'print if abs($F[3] - 1002) == 1' mypasswd
```

The options are: `-a` = autosplit to array `@F` (indexing starts at **zero**), `-F:` = use `:` as field separator, `-ne` run the script here for each line

The anchors to start/end of line (`^` and `$`) are necessary so that numbers like `11001` or `10010` don't match.

Comment: The regex variants here would miss lines where the number starts with a leading zero, but I hope nobody does that... (it would be in danger of being interpreted as octal, and that would be bad). I just hope I didn't leave any other mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version that should work for passwd files:

```
 grep -E --color=auto ':[[:alnum:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:(1001|1003):' mypasswd
```

Explanation:

- `grep -E` enables extended regular expressions, so you can use the OR syntax in `(1001|1003)`. (Another consequence of adding `-E` is that you don't need to escape `+` and some other special characters.)
- `--color=auto` is entirely optional; it merely adds colouring to the matched strings.
- `':[[:alnum:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:(1001|1003):'` matches a string consisting of a colon, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by a colon, followed by one or more digits, followed by a colon, followed by either 1001 or 1003, followed by another colon. (In a context where the the second field is *always* "x", you can replace `[[:graph:]]+` with `x`.)
- I am not making any assumptions about what is in the first column, so there is nothing before the first colon.

For the sample data in the question, this gives you the following output (with colouring removed):

```
 northj:x:1003:1003:Jim jones-North:/home/northj:/bin/csh
 denniss:x:1005:1003:Sue Dennis:/home/denniss:/bin/bash
 smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
 jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
 smithd:x:1055:1001:Dan Smith Jr:/export/home/smithd:/bin/csh
```

Comment: Here, too, `[[:graph:]]+` can eat through an additional colon, and the numbers might match on the comment field. You could use `[^:]+` instead, but then the first colon might match the _second_ colon in the line. Also the trailing `(1001|1003)` would match `10010`, you'd need a `:` in the end to stop that. Using `grep` for stuff like this is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You said in [a comment (now deleted)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551988/80216#comment1024740_551991)

> I need to print the whole line for this to work,
>   but the 4th field value should be highlighted.

The only was `grep` can “highlight” a “field value” is to color it. 
If you want to do that, we can extend [Stéphane Chazelas’s refinement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551988/80216#comment1025136_551992)
on [ilkkachu’s refinement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551988/80216#comment1025113_551992) on [StrongBad’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/551988/80216#551992):

```
grep -E '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(1001|1003):[^:]*:[^:]*:' mypasswd
```

and (assuming that this is GNU `grep`, which is normal on Linux)
add some PCRE magic:

```
grep --color -P '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:\K(1001|1003)(?=:[^:]*:[^:]*:)' mypasswd
```

The **`\K`** is the “keep out” (a.k.a. “kill”) syntax
that says that the text matched by the regular expression so far
should be excluded from the regex match. 
The `(?=regex)` is a (positive) lookahead;
it says that the `1001` or `1003` should be matched
only if it is followed by a colon and three more fields.

Given the input file in the question,
the above command produces the following output:

```
northj:x:1003:1003:Jim jones-North:/home/northj:/bin/csh
denniss:x:1005:1003:Sue Dennis:/home/denniss:/bin/bash
smitha:x:1050:1001:Amy Smith:/export/home/smitha:/bin/bash
jonesc:x:1053:1001:Cathy Jones:/export/home/jonesc:/bin/ksh
smithd:x:1055:1001:Dan Smith Jr:/export/home/smithd:/bin/csh
```

where the bold italic text is colored.

Answer (score 0):

Hop 3 times and perch at the 3rd colon. Then perform a search from where we left off and look for 1001 or 1003 before hitting a colon. If search is a success, print the line.

```
$ perl -ne ' /:/g;//g;//g;/\G100[13]:/&&print' file
```

Gnu sed

```
$ sed -e 'h;s/:/\n/4;/:100[13]\n/!d;g' file
```